# how to add groups attribute in qweb template

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I want to add groups attribute in qweb template like this:

```
<t t-extend="UserMenu">
    <t t-jquery=".dropdown-menu" t-operation="replace">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" data-menu="settings">Preferences</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-menu="account">My Odoo.com account</a></li>
            <li groups="custom_preference_menu.group_yook_about_menu"><a href="#" data-menu="about">About Odoo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-menu="help">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-menu="logout">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </t>
</t>
```

but it'is not working.
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @George Daramouskas

I'd like to hide for example the ''A propos de odoo" menu based on a group.
 See the image on this [screenshot](http://imgur.com/JdClHlx)

Comment: are you created security group? and working perfect?

Answer (score 0):

Well the syntax is right. Are you sure that you selected the right group with module_where_the_group_is_created.group_name?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an incomplete answer. It will hide the `Preferences` menu item for non-admin users:

`xml`:

```
    <t t-extend="UserMenu">
        <t t-jquery="div.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right" t-operation="replace">
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                <a role="menuitem" href="#" data-menu="shortcuts" class="dropdown-item d-none d-md-inline-block">Shortcuts</a>
                <a role="menuitem" href="#" data-menu="settings" class="dropdown-item" id="preference_menuitem">Preferences</a>
                <a role="menuitem" href="#" data-menu="logout" class="dropdown-item">Log out</a>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
```

`js`:

```
 odoo.define('pos_custom_ui.custom_menuitems', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var config = require('web.config');
    var UserMenu = require('web.UserMenu');

    UserMenu.include({
        start: function () {
            var self = this;
            var session = this.getSession();
            if (!session.is_admin){
                this.$('#preference_menuitem').hide();
            }

            this.$el.on('click', '[data-menu]', function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var menu = $(this).data('menu');
                self['_onMenu' + menu.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + menu.slice(1)]();
            });
            return this._super.apply(this, arguments).then(function () {
                var $avatar = self.$('.oe_topbar_avatar');
                if (!session.uid) {
                    $avatar.attr('src', $avatar.data('default-src'));
                    return Promise.resolve();
                }
                var topbar_name = session.name;
                if (config.isDebug()) {
                    topbar_name = _.str.sprintf("%s (%s)", topbar_name, session.db);
                }
                self.$('.oe_topbar_name').text(topbar_name);
                var avatar_src = session.url('/web/image', {
                    model:'res.users',
                    field: 'image_128',
                    id: session.uid,
                });
                $avatar.attr('src', avatar_src);
            });
        },
    });
});
```

Include the `js` file in `web.assets_backend`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="custom_dashboard" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_custom_ui/static/src/js/custom_menuitems.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```